# How do I use the ReSharper custom HTML harness for JavaScript testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, resharper

I've tried everything with this option trying to create a custom HTML harness for my QUnit tests. I've consulted the limited documentation on their site but am getting nowhere, even though I've tried pretty much every combination of path syntax and option from the "Test harness location" dropdown.

I have copied the default implementation to a test html file, and modified it very simply to have some custom titles and elements inside, but no matter where I put the file or how I define a path to it, every time I run the unit tests using ReSharper's test runner, either from inside a file containing tests, or running tests on the project, I just see the default ReSharper QUnit screen.

I've also tried to use this using PhantomJS and not the browser to no avail.

I should be able to use this option to customize an HTML page for my JS tests, using syntax identical to Chutzpah, correct? I am using Resharper 9.0.0.0.

Here's the contents of the file I'm attempting to point ReSharper to:

(update: here's the fixed file that works with Jasmine)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>testing!!!</title>
    @@ReferencedCSSFiles@@
    @@TestFrameworkDependencies@@
    @@ReferencedJSFiles@@
    @@ReSharperIntegration@@
</head>

<body>
    Some Custom Content Here
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, most VS integrated solutions (including Chutzpah) don't work very well.

For some time, my solution to testing in Visual Studio, is to have a recent version of node.js (or io.js) installed, with a package.json and gulp tasks setup to run tests as a pre/post build event.  I tend to favor mocha for tests, but qunit should be possible as well.

I believe that the latest Node Tools for Visual Studio (NTVS) does include gulp task runner integration.

Comment: I agree with the grunt/gulp approach overall (I prefer VS 2013 plugins and native VS2015 support), however it's a bit too much overhead for my current project/task. Right now the Resharper Test Runner is actually meeting my needs with the exception of not being able to add a fixture div, and it looks like a custom HTML template could address this. I'm just having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to get the thing to work...

Answer (score 2):

I changed my test syntax to Jasmine, and it worked. ReSharper doesn't appear to use this template when running QUnit tests.

Comment: Did you actually get it to work? I'm struggling with the same thing. I am using Jasmine but when I use the harness it won't even launch Chrome anymore.

Comment: @Rogier21 Yeah, once I switched to Jasmine it started working. I just have it set up like `file.html` if sitting beside my test, or `path/to/file.html` from solution or project folder and it works. I'm using version 2.0